# Behavior of & followed by * operator

Tags: c, language-lawyer

I have a question about the behavior of the address-of operator followed by a dereference operator.

Let's take a look at the expression `&*p` where `p` is of type `int *`.

The C11 standard (section 6.5.3.2) says:

> The unary
>   &
>   operator yields the address of its operand.  If the operand has type ‘‘
>   type
>   ’’,
>   the  result  has  type  ‘‘pointer  to
>   type
>   ’’.  If the  operand  is  the  result  of  a  unary
>   *
>   operator,
>   neither  that  operator  nor  the
>   &
>   operator  is  evaluated  and  the  result  is  as  if  both  were
>   omitted,  except  that  the  constraints  on  the  operators  still  apply  and  the  result  is  not  an lvalue.

With the footnote:

> Thus, &*E is equivalent to E (even if E is a null pointer), and &(E1[E2]) to ((E1)+(E2)). It is always  true  that  if E is  a  function  designator  or an  lvalue  that  is  a  valid  operand  of  the  unary & operator, *&E is a function designator or an lvalue equal to E. If *P is an lvalue and T is the name of an object pointer type, *(T)P is an lvalue that has a type compatible with that to which T points. Among  the  invalid  values  for  dereferencing a pointer by the unary * operator  are  a  null  pointer, an address inappropriately aligned for the type of object pointed to, and the address of an object after the end of its lifetime.

It is clear that `&*p` has to be equal to `p` except that `&*p` is not an lvalue.

If we now consider `a` with type `int[10]`, what type is `&*a`?
And should there be a difference between for example `sizeof a` and `sizeof &*a`?

On the one side if we evaluate `&*a`, `a` would decay to `int *` with the dereference operator it will become `int` and with the address-of operator then `int *`.

On the other side if `&*a` behaves "as if both were omitted" the type should be `int[10]`.

A short [example](https://ideone.com/7lGoB8) reveals that gcc treats the expression different:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a[10];

    printf("%zu\n%zu\n", sizeof a, sizeof &*a);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
40
8
```

Is this in agreement with the C11 standard?

Maybe it is because the "constraints on the operators still apply" and the operand of the dereference operator has to be a pointer?

Comment: Someone VTCed as not clear. What is not clear? The question is demonstrating GCC behavior seemingly not complying the standard and asking what is wrong.

Comment: BTW, Microsoft compilers (C and C++) behave the same way.

Comment: I would personally expect the behavior demonstrated by GCC rather than the proposed equivalence. The `*a` has a type of `int`, so I would think `&(int)anything` to return `int*`.

Comment: Does the standard say that the `E` is anything for which `*E` is valid (i.e. including arrays)? I don't see a mention of it in the quoted text.

Comment: Your “maybe” sounds spot on.

Comment: clang also exhibits this behavior.

Comment: `a` is an lvalue, but `&*a` is not an lvalue.

Comment: @Ry- The problem i have with this explanation is following: `&*` has to be followed by a pointer which `a` decays to. But since `&*` is then omitted why should `a` still decay?

Comment: @IanAbbott Since `a` is an array i don't think it is a lvalue

Comment: @Osiris It is an lvalue, but not a modifiable one.

Comment: Well, this text seem to hold under the constraints. So if `E` is a pointer, the paragraph cited is true. If it is not (I.e. E is *not* a pointer) different rules apply, and `&*E` is not the same as `E`, so it is not the same as if it was omitted.

Comment: Note: I can compile `void *p = &a;`, but not `void *q = &(&*a);`

Comment: @Osiris [Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53656118/behavior-of-followed-by-operator?noredirect=1#comment94171328_53656118) was simply to point out an example where "Thus, &*E is equivalent to E" is not true - likely because some pre-condition was not met.

Comment: @chux Oh, i see.

Comment: To clarify what I wrote earlier, anything with type `int[10]` must be an lvalue, but `&*a` is not an lvalue and therefore `&*a` cannot have type `int[10]`.

Comment: @chux Hm... That is a nice example, but I don't think it is true "*some pre-condition was not met*". I think the pre-conditions are met, and `&(&*a)` still omits the first `&*` pair, but it gets converted into an rvalue. In other words, `&*E` is equivalent to `E` except for the rvalue and pointer conversion, i.e. we could say `&*E` is equivalent to `as_rvalue(as_pointer(E))`, no?

Comment: @Acorn Perhaps. I was simply adding observed compilation results.  Detail:  gcc reports " error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand" with `&(&*a)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consider that the conversion from array to pointer-to-first-element happens separately and before the application of `*`. Although the decision about whether to convert the array to a pointer is not made until the C implementation determines whether it is the operand of `sizeof` or `&` (per C 2018 6.3.2.1 3), this conversion is not part of the `*` operation. Thus, by the time we are examining `&*`, the operand must already be a pointer.

Furthermore, a constraint on the operand of the `*` operator is that it shall have pointer type (C 2018 6.5.3.2 2). Therefore, the operand must be a pointer, not an array.

The phrasing “the result is as if both were omitted” motivates us to consider what the result would be if both were omitted, but the text goes on to say “except that the constraints on the operators still apply and the result is not an lvalue.” Since the constraints still apply, the operand **must** be a pointer; it is not logically consistent that the constraint could apply and the operand could be an array that has not been converted to a pointer.

Comment: It seems that this actually is the answer. Just because they are omitted does not mean they were never there, and an array type would violate the constraint.

Comment: No, it just means that they are *not* omitted in the array case.

Comment: @EugeneSh. They are omitted, but the type of the operand is already a pointer per the constraints. Anyway, since it is an array, it would not matter whether they are omitted, or not (it would always be valid, whether evaluated or not, not like e.g. in the null case).

Comment: @Acorn No. Constraints do not change types. Operator evaluation does.

Comment: @EugeneSh "Constraints do not change types. Operator evaluation does." Alternatively, you could say "Operators do." I.e. it is the operator that changes the type, whether or not the operator is evaluated.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The constraint does not change the type, but regardless of any other rules and how you arrive to a pointer, your operand must be a pointer, which implies that the result will be `sizeof(int *)`.