# The behavior of unary & operator when met []

Tags: c

I've been reading C11 6.5.3.2 p3

> The unary & operator yields the address of its operand. If the operand has type “type”, the result has
>   type “pointer to type”. If the operand is the result of a unary * operator, neither that operator nor
>   the & operator is evaluated and the result is as if both were omitted, except that the constraints on
>   the operators still apply and the result is not an lvalue. Similarly, if the operand is the result of a []
>   operator, neither the & operator nor the unary * that is implied by the [] is evaluated and the result
>   is as if the & operator were removed and the [] operator were changed to a+ operator. Otherwise,
>   the result is a pointer to the object or function designated by its operand.

I can't understand most of this paragraph although reading it repeatedly.
My problem parts are `* that is implied by the []`, `[]operator were changed to a + operator`, `function designated by this operand`. This paragraph is talking about & but why does * appear and term "function designated" appear after saying []. And `[] operator were changed to a + operator` seems trying to say the definition of array : `E1[E2] = *((E1) + (E2))` What does these lines mean? I need some help.

Comment: For any array of pointer `a` and index `i`, the expression `a[i]` is *exactly* equal to `*(a + i)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53656118/behavior-of-followed-by-operator?

Comment: Otherwise (if unary `&` isn't combined with `*` or `[]`), the result (of unary `y`) is a pointer to the object (`&object`) or function (`&function`) designated by its operand (an `object` or a `function`). Clear?

Comment: @PSkocik Ok, `Otherwise, the result is a pointer to the object or function designated by its operand.` is now clear. But I still have problem with previous sentences

Comment: @Some programmer dude Is `[] operator were changed to a + operator` equal to what you said?

Comment: @TarekD I can't sure `[]`'s meaning. It's not written as `array[i]` just `[]`. That makes me more confuse. So I can't find something at that link.

Comment: @TarekD: Not a duplicate. That is a language-lawyer question about a particular point. This is a less pedantic question on more of a new-to-reading-the-C-standard level.

Comment: Be aware that the ISO standard is not intended to tell humans how to code in C; rather it describes how a compiler must behave in terms of translating the source code. In order to ensure that it is entirely unambiguous so that all compilers apply the same semantics to any code, the description is necessarily tortuous. To that extent trying to understand this stuff in detail is probably of little benefit if you are not writing a compiler

Comment: Your quoted text starts "Similarly..." implying that the preceding _omitted_ text contains important context to the following text.  It does - you should probably include that for context.

Comment: @Clifford I am C beginner for my first programming language without any computer knowledge and I read basic C book 1 time. I think reading standard's syntax, constraints and semantics makes my code flexible. And reading standard don't need to doubt. It is formal document. I think doing this is better than searching website.

Comment: @Clifford I added omitted part, I agree with that "Similarly" is related with preceding text and I want to let you know now I understand what I asked.

Comment: @lev.1code : I have to disagree - the ISO standard is no substitute for a clear reference text.  The fact that you have had to ask this question is proof of that.   You have in this case learned that `&*a == a` - something you did not really need to know, and could infer from simply understanding that `&` and `*` are reciprocal.  Using web resources is fine if you choose reputable sources, just the same as choosing a book.  But you don't learn to drive a car by learning to build one, which is analogous to what you are doing here.

Comment: @Clifford The proof is started by using some definitions or clear something, but that is specified at Standard, isn't it? A website or book's explain is also based on definitions in Standard. I think trying to read all of Standard is equal to your metaphor. but reading what I want is helpful for me. Standard has entry barrier for beginner, but when I become skilled to read that, I think it will become good book or website for me.

Comment: @lev.1code : Over 30 years of professional development tells me that your approach is misguided.  You are entirely free to ignore that advice.  You have cited one paragraph from thousands - it is going to be very slow going if you have to ask for similar interpretations for other parts.  A good reference will distil the important parts and provide examples and explanations you are seeking here.   Programming is a skill independent of and broader then any particular programming language.  You might end up knowing everything about the language, but nothing about using it productively.

Comment: @Clifford That is only my pure thought may be it's because I studied math and think Standard as axiom. You made me think more. I think good programmer is finally skillful or good at problem solving too, but C is case sensitive language. In order to use this advantage, I think I have to understand deeply about C, and it's also base language for others(python, java, c++....), so it seems refering standard is not entirely meaningless, I will avoid seeing standard excessively thanks to your advice.

Comment: From the equivalence follows that `&a[i]` is then `&*(a + i)` which is equal to `a + i`. And if `i == 0` then comes the whole array-decay thing (when `a` is equal to `&a[0]`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If the operand is the result of a unary * operator, neither that
>   operator nor the & operator is evaluated and the result is as if both
>   were omitted, except that the constraints on the operators still apply
>   and the result is not an lvalue.

Unary `&` applied to the result of unary `*`, cancels the `*` and converts the operand of the original `*` to an r-value:

```
#include <assert.h>
int main()
{
    int *p=&(int){42};
    assert(&*p == p); //the value (42) is not fetched from the target
    #if 0
        &*p = &(int){1000}; //not OK; & cancels the * but converts p to an r-value (can't be on the left-hand side of an assignment)
    #endif
    p = &(int){1000}; //ok; p is an l-value (can be on the left hand side of an assignment)
    //(more accurately: can have its address taken)
}
```

Now since a `pointerOrArray[index]` expression is defined ([6.5.2.1p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.1p2)) as `*(pointerOrArray+index)` (the result of a unary `*`, except the `*` is hidden), you can apply the same rule to it: `&pointerOrArray[index]` <=> `(pointerOrArry+Index)`. That's what your first quoted sentence says.

The last sentence you quoted can be (within the context of [6.5.3.2p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.2p3)) interpreted as:

Otherwise (if unary `&` isn't combined with `*` or `[]`), the result (of unary `&`) is a pointer to the object (`&object`) or function (`&function`) designated by its operand (an `object` or a `function`).

Answer (score 2):

> [From a comment] I can't sure `[]`'s meaning. It's not written as `array[i]` just `[]`.

The C standard uses `[]` to mean the subscript operator. Although it appears in source code as `E1[E2]`, where `E1` and `E2` stand for expressions, the `[` and `]` characters are the fundamental way it is recognized, and they designate an operation of array subscripting.

> [C 2011, draft N1570, 6.5.3.2 3, discussing the unary `&` operator] … Similarly, if the operand is the result of a `[]` operator, neither the `&` operator nor the unary `*` that is implied by the `[]` is evaluated and the result is as if the `&` operator were removed and the `[]` operator were changed to a `+` operator. Otherwise, the result is a pointer to the object or function designated by its operand.

Going back to the `[]` operator, consider an expression `E1[E2]`. The definition of the subscript operator, in 6.5.2.1 2, is that it is identical to `(*((E1)+(E2)))`. (In other words, it takes the pointer `E1` and adds the subscript `E2` to it, then applies `*` to get the element at that location. Or, since `+` is commutative, `E2` can be the pointer, and `E1` can be the subscript.) So “the unary `*` that is implied by the `[]`” is that `*` in `(*((E1)+(E2)))`.

So, when we have `&` applied to `E1[E2]`, this passage tells us to consider it as `&(*((E1)+(E2)))` and that neither the `&` nor the `*` are evaluated, so it is as if it were `((E1)+(E2))`.

> … why does … [the] term "function designated" appear…

The sentence containing “function designated” is separate. The “Otherwise” tells us it is talking about the situation other than when `&` is applied to a subscript expression (from the sentence before) or to a unary `*` expression (from two sentences before). So we just have `&E`, where `E` is something other than `*E1` or `E1[E2]`. This sentence says “Otherwise, the result is a pointer to the object or function designated by its operand.” If `E` is an object, then `&E` is a pointer to the object. If `E` is a function, then `&E` is a pointer to the function.